# c program to read & write text file

Tags: c

Below is a quick program I created,  The program is suppose to keep a trace of blood donors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct donors
{
 char name[20];
 char address[40];
 int age;
 int blood_type;
};

void main()
{
  int ask,i=0;
  struct donors d;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("Blood_Donors.txt","r");


  clrscr();

  if(fp==NULL)
  {
    printf("Error: Unable to open file.");
    printf("\nDo you want to create a new file ? (Y = 1 / N = 0) : ");
    scanf("%d",&ask);
    if(ask==1)
    {
      fp = fopen("Blood_Donors.txt","w");
    }

    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
      printf("\nFile Created\n");
    }
    else
    {
     if(ask==1)
     {
      printf("\nError: Unable to create file");
      printf("\nPress any key to exit the program");
      getch();
      exit(1);
      }
      else
      {
       printf("\nFile not created \nPress any key to exit the program");
       getch();
       exit(1);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
   fp = fopen("Blood_Donors.txt","a");
   printf("Do you want to enter a record ? (Y = 1 / N = 0) : ");
   scanf("%d",&ask);
  }

  while(ask==1)
  {
    i=i+1;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter name (Maximum 20 characters) : ");
    gets(d.name);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter address (Maximum 40 characters) : ");
    gets(d.address);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter age (Maximum 2 characters) : ");
    scanf("%d",&d.age);

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter Blood Type \n(A- = 1, A+ = 2, B- = 3, B+ = 4, AB- = 5, AB+ = 6, O- = 7, O+ = 8) : ");
    scanf("%d",&d.blood_type);

    fprintf(fp,"<donor %d>\nName: %s\nAddress: %s\nAge: %d\nType: %d\n\n",i, d.name, d.address, d.age, d.blood_type);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\n\nDo you want to enter another record ? (Y = 1 / N = 0) : ");
    scanf("%d",&ask);
   }

  fclose(fp);
  getch();
}
```

a) how to increase the value of i appropriately ? where i holds the number of the previous donor.
b) how to print the details of all donors below age 30 and whose name starts with 's' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)Since you are saving to a file, why not declare the first line of the file as a single number i representing the number of donors so far, followed by i lines of donors?

b)you might want to lookup xml's

Comment: I can't use xml , is it possible to find the age using fseek and then fread that whole line and 2 or 3 lines after it ?

Comment: well it really depends on what you want the program to achieve. If you want it to perform. If you want it to be the least efficient you would want to use some kind of data structure. Otherwise it could take a very long time to load/add to the file

if you really cant then you could always do your string parsing but it could be very slow and tedious to debug

If you do want the data structure path, organize using a kd-tree(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or even an b-tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) would dramatically improve your efficiency. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can store these users in a data structure, such as a LinkedList and then iterate through the linked list to find all users whos name starts with "s" and you can count the items that way too.